# Hash Sum Mismatch in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates

I have just installed 18.04 LTS. However, I cannot update.
I am getting this error of hashsum mismatch.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-tweaks
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-tweak-tool gnome-tweaks
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 471 not upgraded.
Need to get 218 kB/219 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,257 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://202.88.160.186:80/data/02bfdb96e8b9e520/in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 gnome-tweaks all 3.28.1-1 [218 kB]
Err:1 http://202.88.160.186:80/data/02bfdb96e8b9e520/in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 gnome-tweaks all 3.28.1-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:d2fe9e737713b92b3df4875fffeca2b17b66490b1d1e9d061d9d96695cc90439
   - SHA1:6e4d32fdfd7cbcd18bcac4a6adf4e875bcc428cd [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8835ebc5efb295b47b1ac5d460cca314 [weak]
   - Filesize:217600 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:cc60e53fa87b7fa723d35599972fd830ac7d8e74f9c1fa48de9e192752b22614
   - SHA1:3c5e500644f32bcb23de03e39d6a6b4828bd03a8 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:477873e66b2350f4c63fa5ca881d22d0 [weak]
   - Filesize:217600 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 08:56:42 +0000
Fetched 218 kB in 2s (101 kB/s)       
E: Failed to fetch http://202.88.160.186:80/data/02bfdb96e8b9e520/in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-tweaks/gnome-tweaks_3.28.1-1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:d2fe9e737713b92b3df4875fffeca2b17b66490b1d1e9d061d9d96695cc90439
    - SHA1:6e4d32fdfd7cbcd18bcac4a6adf4e875bcc428cd [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8835ebc5efb295b47b1ac5d460cca314 [weak]
    - Filesize:217600 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:cc60e53fa87b7fa723d35599972fd830ac7d8e74f9c1fa48de9e192752b22614
    - SHA1:3c5e500644f32bcb23de03e39d6a6b4828bd03a8 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:477873e66b2350f4c63fa5ca881d22d0 [weak]
    - Filesize:217600 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 08:56:42 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried all possible methods from previously asked questions like.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

and

Just remove all the content of /var/lib/apt/lists directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```

nothing worked...!!!

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.
I switched to a different mirror of a different country

[image: Server i am currently using]

Comment: This is not working. I'm searching for different solution. If I find then I will write here.